# Custom sorting of dates

Tags: java, datetime, sorting, collections, lambda

I have implemented a class which implements a list of my custom `DateObj`. I have sorted the list in a peculiar manner based on the current month. I achieved my desired results, but I'm required to call `Collections.sort()` four times to achieve it. I feel this could be improved. Any thoughts?

```
//Custom Date Object
public class DateObj {

private int year;
private int month;
private int date;

DateObj(int year, int month ,int date){
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.date = date;
}

public Integer getYear() {return year;}
public Integer getMonth() {return month;}
public Integer getDate() {return date;}
}
```

The custom sort class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomListSort {
 static List<DateObj> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String a[]){

createRandomDateObjs();

Integer CURRENTMONTH = 6;

//Sort Months Descending
Collections.sort(list,(arg0,arg1)-> arg1.getMonth().compareTo(arg0.getMonth()));

//Sort by keeping the object with nearest largest next month first
Collections.sort(list,(arg0,arg1)->CURRENTMONTH.compareTo(arg0.getMonth()));

//Sort the months which were pushed back in an ascending order.
Collections.sort(list,(arg0,arg1)->(arg0.getMonth()<=CURRENTMONTH && arg1.getMonth()<=CURRENTMONTH)? arg0.getMonth().compareTo(arg1.getMonth()):0);

//If months same sort them in ascending manner based on their dates
Collections.sort(list, (arg0,arg1)->(arg0.getMonth() == arg1.getMonth())  ? arg0.getDate().compareTo(arg1.getDate()) : 0);

System.out.println("\nDESIRED OUTPUT");
System.out.println("\nMM - DD - YYYY \n");

for(int i = 0 ; i<list.size();i++)
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getMonth() +" - "+list.get(i).getDate()+" - "+list.get(i).getYear());        
}

static void createRandomDateObjs(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i<20 ; i++){
        int y = 1980;
            y+=(int)(Math.random()*55);
        int m = (int) (Math.random()*11);
        int d = (int) (Math.random()*30);
        list.add(new DateObj(++y,++m,++d)); //Pre-increment to change 0's to 1's
}
}
```

Initially I had implemented it using Comparators but the Lambda made the code much cleaner.

Desired output:

> ```
> MM - DD - YYYY 
>
> 7 - 20 - 2023
> 7 - 18 - 2027
> 8 - 30 - 2010
> 8 - 12 - 2020
> 9 - 21 - 2006
> 10 - 23 - 2008
> 11 - 19 - 2000
> 11 - 16 - 2033
> 11 - 13 - 1989
> 12 - 13 - 2019
> 1 - 10 - 1985
> 1 - 15 - 2016
> 4 - 10 - 2021
> 4 - 13 - 2022
> 4 - 14 - 2004
> 5 - 1 - 2025
> 5 - 4 - 2014
> 5 - 20 - 2023
> 5 - 21 - 2022
> 6 - 29 - 1990
> ```

Comment: You've been told on your [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975518/reduce-number-of-calls-to-collections-sort-for-custom-sorting-of-list-of-objec?noredirect=1#comment57680809_34975518) that you can use `Comparator.thenComparing` on Java 8 to achieve this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Comparator` is the correct approach, you just need to mod the month by the current month before comparing them. The easiest way to do this is to introduce a static variable `currentMonth` to hold the current month for all instances of `DateObj`.

Add `DateObj.setCurrentMonth(CURRENTMONTH);` to your `Main`, and use the code below:

```
//Custom Date Object
class DateObj implements Comparable<DateObj>{

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int date;
    private static int currentMonth;

    DateObj(int year, int month ,int date){
      this.year = year;
      this.month = month;
      this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {return year;}
    public Integer getMonth() {return month;}
    public Integer getDate() {return date;}
    public Integer getCurrentMonth() { return DateObj.currentMonth;}
    public static void setCurrentMonth(int currentMonth){
        DateObj.currentMonth = currentMonth;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DateObj o) {
        int months = (month+(12-currentMonth))%12 - (o.month+(12-currentMonth))%12;
        if(months == 0)
            return this.date-o.date;
        else{
            return months;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** An alternative approach is to simply define the `Comparator` in your `main` body. This avoids the use a static value to hold `currentMonth`:

```
    Collections.sort(list, (o1,o2)->{
            int months = (o1.getMonth()+(12-CURRENTMONTH))%12 - (o2.getMonth()+(12-CURRENTMONTH))%12;
            if(months == 0)
                return o1.getDate()-o2.getDate();
            else{
                return months;
            }
    });
```

**Thanks to Mr.Wiggles** for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

Your current code has several flaws:

- Do not return an `Integer` object when an `int` suffice. It might create an unnecessary object. I would rewrite your getter like this

  ```
  public int getYear() {
      return year;
  }
  ```
- You should properly indent and format your code, as it makes it a lot easier to read. For example, the getter can be written more clearly like the snippet above.
- You are indeed comparing 4 times the list when you can do it in one pass.
- Your usage of `static` is awkward. You should get rid of it and make the method `createRandomDateObjs()` return the created list of `DateObj`.
- Don't name your local variable `CURRENTMONTH`. If it is a constant, make it `private static final int` instead.

---

The heart of the comparator is about comparing the month of the dates. Instead of using 3 separate comparator, consider the following one. Given 2 `DateObj` `o1` and `o2`:

- If the months of `o1` and `o2` are both strictly greater than 6, the one being closer to 6 should be sorted before the other one.
- If the months of `o1` and `o2` are both lower or equal to 6, the one being closer to 6 should be sorted after the other one.

(Those two conditions takes care of the fact that the month 6 should be sorted at the end of the list)

- If they have different signs, we need an extra logic:

  - If the month of `o1` is strictly after 6 (so the month of `o2` is before 6), it means that `o1` should be sorted before `o2` so we must return a negative value (like `-1`).
  - On the contrary, if the month of `o1` is before or equal to 6 (so the month of `o2` is after 6), it means that `o1` should be sorted after `o2` so we must return a positive value (like `1`).

This would an implementation of this comparator using a lambda expression:

```
    Comparator<DateObj> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
        int diff1 = o1.getMonth() - CURRENTMONTH;
        int diff2 = o2.getMonth() - CURRENTMONTH;
        if (diff1 > 0 && diff2 > 0 || diff1 <= 0 && diff2 <= 0) {
            return diff1 - diff2;
        } else if (diff1 > 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (diff1 <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
```

The advantage with this reasoning over using modular arithmetic is that it will work for whatever value (even negative value). The answer by [Austin D](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/95630/austin-d) assumes that all value are positive and between 0 and 11 (it could be made mode flexible but then you would first have to determine the maximum value). It only works for this particular case (because a month always verifies that assumption).

Then, in case the month are equal, your code is sorting based on the date field. With Java 8, you can compose multiple comparator with [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-). In this case, we will then compare with an `int` so we can use [`Comparator.thenComparingInt(keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), where the key extractor returns the date.

The final comparator would be:

```
    Comparator<DateObj> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
        int diff1 = o1.getMonth() - CURRENTMONTH;
        int diff2 = o2.getMonth() - CURRENTMONTH;
        if (diff1 > 0 && diff2 > 0 || diff1 <= 0 && diff2 <= 0) {
            return diff1 - diff2;
        } else if (diff1 > 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (diff1 <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
comparator = comparator.thenComparingInt(DateObj::getDate);

list.sort(comparator);
```